# changing an element when screen dimensions change

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design, browserstack

I am using semanticcss framework. I have two navigation menus one for desktop and the other for mobile. 
I am using this css:

```
#mob {
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    #desktop {
        display: none;
    }
    #mob {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

It works on google chrome when i resize the windows but it doesnt work on the two android devices i have tested. I also tested it using ios7 with browserstack but with no luck.

my live site is here: http://kaylins-sites.azurewebsites.net/default.aspx

and the rest of the code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cu3aR/

Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: what problem you are facing on android device? I mean does it not changing is state?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Dlf9CdV.jpg     
http://i.imgur.com/jvv2rPk.png     
http://i.imgur.com/G1xz8Dn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include this in `<head></head>`

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" /> <-- user-scalable=yes if you want user to allow zoom -->
```

change you @media style as this

```
@media only screen (max-width: 960px) {
    #desktop {
        display: none;
    }
    #mob {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Now I try to explain maybe..:)

```
@media (max-width:960px)
```

for a window with a `max-width` of `960px` that you want to apply these styles. At that size you would be talking about anything smaller than a desktop screen in most cases.

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px)
```

for a device with a `screen` and a window with `max-width` of `960px` apply the style. This is almost identical to the above except you are specifying `screen` as opposed to the [other media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)  the most common other one being `print`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:960px)
```

Here is a [quote](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0) straight from W3C to explain this one.

> The keyword ‘`only`’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents. User   agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

As there is no such media type as "`only`", the style sheet should be ignored by older browsers.

Comment: thanks for the response. But this does not work it does not even change when the browser window is re sized as previous. I have tested this on my phone and tablet but it still shows the original navigation bar.

Comment: sorry it was a silly mistake on my part the: @media screen and (max-width:960px) method works really well.
thanks